# How to test Jquery Mobile web App on an iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, testing, mobile, web

I have an iPhone and a local mobile web app created on my desktop. I can't figure out how to test this web app on my iPhone. What is it I need to do to run and test the web app on the iPhone?

Comment: What is the local web app written in? Is it just static HTML or something like PHP or Node?

Comment: It is Jquery Mobile so HTML.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cordova-browser/id573787308?mt=8      Use cordova web browser in your mobile simply  provide your local url in that browser and then you can test your application and important think is your computer and your mobile has to be in same network

Answer (score 0):

You could use the iPhone Simulator bundled with Xcode - simply navigate to your site using the simulated Safari app. This is handy since it'll pick up a localhost environment, whereas your iPhone won't.

If you're only on Windows though then I believe you're out of luck.

Comment: I want to test movement with the actual phone itself, such as when you flip it horizontally. Also, I may be limited to a Windows PC.

Comment: The simulator supports different orientations as well - it tries to do just about everything an iPhone does so apps can be tested in an environment that reflects 'the real world' as closely as possible.